# How to set the visual size of one component based on another component in the same type?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am using Dymola. Assuming that I have two components in my model, I want to use the same visual size for the components that share the same type.

So how could I set the visual size of one component according to another one?
I am not planning to use annotation code, cause that could be too much trouble when there are many components?

[image]

Comment: You want to resize other components depending on the actual size of one component? Like you resize the bigger example in your screenshot and the smaller one immediately has the same size?

Comment: Like I want to resize the bigger one so that it has the same size as the smaller one.

Comment: Manually or automatically?

Comment: Manually would be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using annotations will be the only way to go. This is where the position and size of a component are determined. The only way that comes to my mind is using parameters to set these positions as (partially) shown below.

```
model pos_params
  parameter Real pos_x1 = -10;

  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{pos_x1,-10},{10,10}})));
end pos_params;
```

To get to your result you would need to have some additional parameters in multiple components.

Still, doing this in Dymola will make make the graphical manipulation of size an position of a model cumbersome, as the icon will be set to have zero size.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way around annotations, because they define the graphical representation of components. But you can copy-paste the relevant `extent` values easily from one component to another using the `Annotation` window.

[image: Annotation window in Dymola]

Comment: Thank you for the advice, that would save a lot of trouble for me.